# Why is it advantageous if a contiguous working set fits on a single page?

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-address, virtual-memory

I am new to virtual memory and heard that large / huge pages are efficient to use, if a program has a very large, contiguous working set, so that this set fits on one page. I don't see why this is the case. Why would this be more efficient than splitting the working set into multiple pages?

Comment: More pages = more cache turnover = slower processing, since the CPU doesn't have all that much room available for page mapping in the [TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer). Having it all on one page means the working set has a much better chance of being in the cache (but even if doesn't fit on one page, having fewer pages is better).

Comment: @JeroenMostertwhy would the chance of being in the cache be higher ? Also, this sounds like the most efficient thing would be to have just one page that contains all mappings and clearly this is not practical